# Как подключить поиск на всех страницах?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, у меня есть layout: _navigation.html.erb, а в нем код для поиска:

```
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group search_margin">
          <%= form_tag film_sessions_path, :method => 'get', class:"navbar-form navbar-left" do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class:"form-control", placeholder:"Search" %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", class:"btn btn-raised btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
        <span class="material-input"></span></div>
      </form>
```

Далее в контроллере film_sessions:

```
  def index
    @film_sessions = FilmSession.where(["session_name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%"])
    @film_sessions = FilmSession.where(["session_name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%"])
  end
```

Выходит, что поиск работает только на странице film_sessions_path. Как прикрутить его к любой странице сайта, что-бы при нажатии на кнопку поиска, выполнялось перенаправление на film_sessions_path?

**Разметка формы**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group search_margin">
      <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="фыв" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Search" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary">
        <span class="material-input"></span>
        <span class="material-input"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: *Выходит, что поиск работает только на странице film_sessions_path.* -- чегой-то?

Comment: На других страницах просто происходит перезагрузка и добавление к их адресу: ?utf8=✓&search=фыв&commit=Search

Comment: Покажите разметку отрендерившейся в результате этого формы.

Comment: Обновил вопрос)

Comment: Интересные, однако, дела. А если `pry`нуться внутри вьюхи и посмотреть в `film_sessions_path`, что там?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, если перейти по film_session_path (view - index короче говоря), и запустить поиск там, то он работает, а вот на других страницах не хочет. Форма рендерится точно такая же

Comment: Сделать в этой вьюхе `binding.pry` и посмотреть значение `film_sessions_path` на "других страницах".

Comment: Не использовал pry до этого( 
В методе index контроллера film_sessions добавил binding.pry. 
Далее в консоли написал film_sessions_path и мне выдало "/film_sessions". Написал binding.pry в методе new, после так же в консоли написал film_sessions_path и мне выдало "/film_sessions". Не так что-то делаю?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем html-ный `<form>` и в нём ресльсовый `form_tag`? Последний добавляет тот же тэг `form` а стандарты HTML не разрешают их вложенность. Вот браузер и пытается "исправить".
Правильно, видимо так:

```
<%= form_tag film_sessions_path, :method => 'get', class:"navbar-form navbar-left" do %>
  <div class="form-group search_margin">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class:"form-control", placeholder:"Search" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", class:"btn btn-raised btn-primary" %>
    <span class="material-input"></span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно!)